# Entity 'Entity-RelationshipDefinition-CatalogToCategory' was not found in sitecore commerce

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am using sitecore 10 commerce. in that i am creating new catalog but while add the new category via business tool it shows following error message.

```
CtxMsg.Error.EntityNotFound: Text=Entity not found for Source:Entity-Catalog-Webshop_Product, Target:Entity-Category-Webshop_Product-SampleTest, Relationship type:CatalogToCategory
PipelineAbort:Entity not found for Source:Entity-Catalog-Webshop_Product, Target:Entity-Category-Webshop_Product-SampleTest, Relationship type:CatalogToCategory
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to first create Relationship Definitions. You will find this section in Business Tools.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am new to Sitecore commerce so I need  blog or guidance for step by step site implementation .so can you please refer me any other source except official document.

Answer (score 0):

This issue means your environment wasn't initialized properly.
Try these steps from Postman:

1-Clean Environment
2-Bootstrap
3-Initialize Environment